# KotH - Floating Point Prisoners Dilemma

Tags: game, king-of-the-hill, python, floating-point

### Background

So, nowadays the popular Prisoner's Dilemma variant is the Prisoner's Trilemma, where there are three options. I can easily see that being increased, so I figured

> Why settle for *three* options, when we can have ***INFINITE*** options?

Therefore, I created the Floating Point Prisoner's ?Lemma.

### Equations:

Each round, your score will be calculated as (\$a\$ is what Player 1 returns, \$b\$ is what Player 2 returns):

$$
\text{Player 1 expected score: }\quad 2ab+3(1-a)b+(1-a)(1-b)
$$

$$
\text{Player 2 expected score: }\quad 2ab+3a(1-b)+(1-a)(1-b)
$$

\$3\$ is the temptation payoff, the payoff \$a\$ gets if \$a\$ defects and \$b\$ cooperates. \$2\$ is the reward, for if both cooperate. \$1\$ is the punishment, for if both defect. The sucker's payoff is \$0\$, which is what \$a\$ gets when \$a\$ cooperates and \$b\$ defects.

#### Explanation of what floating point numbers mean in output

Basically, an output of 0.5 means that the figurative probability (The controller is almost deterministic, only matching up contestants at random) of cooperation is 0.5. This means that since the output is closer to 1 than 0 is, the opponent gets some score, but not as much as if the output of the contestant we're focusing on was 1.

### Forbidden Stuff

- Standard Loopholes are forbidden.
- No interacting with the controller other then by returning values in the strategy function.
- No interference with other bots (with global variables, other stuff)
- Global Vars are Highly Discouraged. Instead, use the store dict.
- More stuff may be added

### Generic Stuff

It uses an equation from the wonderful fellows at https://math.stackexchange.com to determine what to do, with the floating point numbers correlating to probability of coop or defect. However, the controller is deterministic in terms of the scoring stuff, and the probabilities are not treated as probabilities. The equations are in the play function in the controller.

**NOTE:** When run, it'll sometimes print something like [[0, 28948.234], [1, 32083.23849], [2, 0]]. That's just an old debugging feature I forgot to remove.

### Technical Stuff

Create a bot that can play this Python implementation of the Prisoner's ?Lemma. Make two functions, `strategy` and `plan`, that are in a similar format as the below examples. Store is cleared after every matchup, you can change this by commenting out the line in run in the controller that says

```
self.store = {
}
```

This is a basic bot template:

```python
def strategy(is_new_game, store):
  # Put Stuff Here™. is_new_game tells the function if it's a new game. returns a value between 0 and 1, where 1 = coop and 0 = defect, and in-between stuff correlates to probability of coop or defect. Store is a dict for storage.
def plan(opmove, store):
  # opmove is the opponents move last round. This function shouldn't return anything. Put pass here if you don't use this.
```

#### Example Bots

♫Coop Bop Bot♫

```python
#Example Contestant
def strategy(is_new_game):
  return 1

def plan(opmove):
  pass
```

Random

```python
#Example Contestant
import random
def strategy(is_new_game):
  return random.random()
def plan(opmove):
  pass
```

Controller is at https://github.com/4D4850/KotH-Floating-Dilemma

Feel free to make a pull request.

## Leaderboard

```
Random, 165500.78318694307
Helped, 147835.72861717656
Cooperator, 125285.07526747975
Random Alternator, 82809.27322624522
Tit for Tat, 51139.558474789665
```

If you don't see your bot, there was an error.

Note: Helped and Random Alternator needed to be slightly modified to run without errors. Also, there was a catastrophic bug in the scoring system, that is now fixed.

Comment: Sandbox: https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges/23498#23498

Comment: Just to be clear about `store`: each bot starts with a store which can be manipulated, right?

Comment: You define a value in the store dict on your own. They don't each have their own dicts predefined.

Comment: Chat room for general ?Lemma related discussion: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126625/prisoners-lemma-general-chat

Comment: Your controller uses the same `self.store` dict for both players. In cases where the same players play against each other, this leads to faulty results, because the bots actually influence each other.

Comment: For reasons I don't really know, the order of the contestants in arena.py heavily influences the outcome. This means that there is a major bug in the controller... I'll report both issues on GitHub as well (hope that helps)...

Comment: I wrote an alternative controller [here](https://github.com/agtoever/floating_koth), in which the two mentioned issues are (to my best knowledge) addressed.

Answer (score 2):

## Helped

```py
def strategy(is_new_game, store):
  if store and store['moves']:
    return store['moves'][-1]
  return .1
def plan(opmove, store):
  if opmove > .5:
    if store and store['moves']:
      store['moves'].append(opmove / 2)
    else:
      store['moves'] = [opmove / 2]
  else:
    if store and store['moves']:
      store['moves'].append(opmove * 2)
    else:
      store['moves'] = [opmove * 2]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##pZHRCoIwFIbv9xTnTo2yLIII7Cm6E5GBRxN0G9ssJHr25VwpSBDR3c5/vp1vnIlOXzjbHYQ0JscClJZUY9n5lcoY3rKSNrjsUy4xOBKAqnAFUJa7U@I1/IrKS20bQKJuJZu1klWUkrEXRsSqRE2Zz4VFZgYXwgnCvRv61QqzNKRCIMtf42EN22DgsFb4@QbEkEy0fe3E/qtf/KTv6dQ4Xwz3BxGyYtofP@Ys23FfARmWuAn372SkbWGe)

`Helped` is a bot that depends on the opponent's previous moves. Picks higher next moves for lower previous moves, and lower ones for higher ones.

Comment: I'm not sure `moves` is a valid index.

Comment: @StackMeter It's not an index. You see, `store` is a dictionary, not a list.

Comment: This seems neat. I'll run the first run today.

Comment: Although I prefer the term array rather than list.

Comment: @4D4850 So do I as I'm more comfortable working with JavaScript, but Python uses lists so I say "list" here and "array" with JS

Comment: Ok. By the way, your the only person who submitted a functional bot! Good Job!

Comment: @4D4850 I'm doing worse than the random one; I really need to up my game.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126624/discussion-between-4d4850-and-recursive-co).

Answer (score 1):

## Random Alternator

```python
store[0] = 0
store[1] = 0
print(store)
import random
def strategy(is_new_game, store):
  if is_new_game or store[0]%100 < 10:
    store[1] += 1
    return random.random()
  else:
      store.append(store[1] + 1, (sum(store)/len(store)))
      store[1] += 1
      return sum(list(store)[1:])/len(list(store)[1:])
def plan(opmove, store):
  store.append(store[1] + 1, opmove)
  store[1] += 1
  store[0] += random.random() + random.random()
  return store
```

Randomly alternates between taking the total average of the moves and random moves in a random way (Hopefully, unexploitable).

Comment: Just FYI, store is a dict rather than an array.

Comment: Although I don't understand it well enough to edit it.

Comment: @4D4850 fixed it

Comment: I still needed to slightly modify it, but I understood how to.

Comment: @4D4850 Thanks for the help.

Comment: You're welcome. The slightly modified version is under the name randalt.py in the controller.

Answer (score 1):

## Tit for Tat

```python
def strategy(is_new_game, store):
    if is_new_game: return 1
    return store[0]
def plan(opmove, store):
    store[0]=opmove
```

Comment: @4D4850 Please stop editing the answers to make them work - leave a comment underneath with what should be done to fix it instead. I've rolled back your edit. att, feel free to roll my rollback back if you'd like their fix to stay

Comment: Also note that `store[0]` works even if `store` is a dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

## Defector

```python
def strategy(n, s):
    return 0

def plan(o, s):
    pass
```

Always defects (returns 0).

Answer (score 1):

## Uppercut

```python
def strategy(is_new_game,*a):
  return -1000000

def plan(opmove,*a):
  pass
```

Returns a negative number with high magnitude to get lots of points. This wasn’t disallowed in the challenge rules.

Answer (score 1):

## Falling Uppercut

```python
def strategy(is_new_game, store):
  if is_new_game:
    return -(1000000**2)
  return -(1000000**store["e"])

def plan(opmove, store):
  if "e" in store:
    store["e"] += 1
  else:
    store["e"] = 3
```

Modified version of Uppercut to counter bots like Helped, Random Alternator and Tit for Tat.

### Edit

This has been edited to counter the original Uppercut.